# Mostrar en render segun valor dentro de localStorage o estado - REACT

Tags: reactjs

Mi app trae info de una api de peliculas. Entre esa info que traigo esta el id que lo almaceno en el localstorage en 'favoritos' y tambien en un estado favoritos.

Cuando hago un mapeo en el render de toda la informacion necesito  preguntar si ese ID está dentro del listado de ID's de favoritos. Si esta en el render mostrar `<p className=" heart d-inline-block">❤️</p>`
y si no esta mostrar
`<p className=" heart d-inline-block" onClick={addFavHandler}></p>`

Bueno no se preguntar esto dentro del render. Les dejo mi codigo completo a ver si me pueden dar una idea.

````
function Movies (){
   
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [ movies, setMovies ] = useState([]);
    const [ favoritos, setFavoritos ] = useState([]);
    
   
    const ArrayIds = [];

  



  const baseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
  const apiKey = '';
  
    //component did mount

    useEffect(() => {
      if (localStorage.length == 0){
        localStorage.setItem("favoritos",JSON.stringify(ArrayIds));
      }
        const getData = async () =>{
            let endPoint =  `${baseURL}popular?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&page=1`; 
            let response = await fetch(endPoint);
            let data = await response.json();
            return data;  
           } 
            getData().then(data =>{
               setMovies(data.results);
               setFavoritos(localStorage.favoritos);
               console.log(favoritos);
               setIsLoading(false);
           });
           
    },[])
    
    const addFavHandler = (e) => {
      const elementoPadre = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
      const myFav = elementoPadre.querySelector(".lopo").innerText;
      console.log(localStorage.favoritos);
      if (localStorage. length === 0) {
        ArrayIds.push(myFav);
            localStorage.setItem("favoritos",JSON.stringify(ArrayIds));
      }else{
        let localList=localStorage.getItem("favoritos");
        console.log(localList);
        let list=JSON.parse(localList);
        list.push(myFav)
        localStorage.setItem("favoritos",JSON.stringify(list));
      }
      
      let localList=localStorage.getItem("favoritos");
      let list=JSON.parse(localList);
        const buscar = list.find(element => myFav);
        if (buscar !=undefined) {
          elementoPadre.querySelector(".heart").innerText = "❤️";
        }
   }
   

  
   
   
    return(
        
            
             <Row>
              
              { isLoading && 
            <div className= "cargando">
              <h3 className="loading"> Loading...</h3>  
              <img className="imgLoading" src={imgLoading} alt="" />
              
           </div>
          }
               {movies.map(oneMovie =>{
                let imagenMovie = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${oneMovie.poster_path}`;
                return(
                    <Col lg={3} sm={6} xs ={12} >
                    <div key ={oneMovie.id}>
                        
                    <Card className="my-2 h-100">
                    
                  <Card.Img className="hovereffect" variant="top" src = {imagenMovie} />
                  <Card.Body>
                   <Card.Title className="titulo d-inline-block">{oneMovie.title.substr(0, 25).trim()}</Card.Title>
                     <p className="lopo">{oneMovie.id}</p>
                   <Card.Text className="resumen" >{oneMovie.overview.substr(0, 90).trim()}...</Card.Text>
                   <Button className="detalles" as={Link} to={`/movie-details/${oneMovie.id}`}>Details</Button>
                       
                 
                   
                                <p className=" heart d-inline-block" onClick={addFavHandler}></p>
                                
                  
                                
                                
                  </Card.Body>
                  
                 </Card>
                 
                 
                 
               </div>
               </Col>
           )
       } )}
       
       </Row>
            
       
         
     )
 }
 export default Movies;```
````

Comment: con el metodo includes de un array puedes buscar el id

Comment: Sugiero que edites la pregunta ocultando el `apiKey`, saludos

Comment: También. un repaso a cómo se extraen los datos de `localstorage` en `scope` JS, por ejemplo esto `localStorage. length === 0` no es de ayuda para lo que se busca completar.

Comment: Una vez que se haya aplicado parse correctamente a localStorage, en la parte `localStorage. length === 0`, comparando ahora algo como `favoritesArrayFromLS. length === 0` tal vez la pieza de código funcione. Sugiero verificar esto.